# How to show customaction menu item depending upon user permission

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a CustomAction menuItem

```
    <CustomAction Id="DocumentManagement.DocLibNewToolbar" Location="EditControlBlock" RegistrationType="ContentType" RegistrationId="0x0101002bae451fbd3640fb9bae5df410b4a9a0" Title="Print">
        <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/ELSActionMenu/PrintListItem.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;ID={ItemId}"/>
  </CustomAction>
```

I know that I can write a SPItemEventReceiver class and check if the current users roles match the criteria. 
But I want to hide this CustomAction on ListItem["Authorized"] =TRUE, is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

As per the title of the the question I understood that you need to show the Custom Action based on the permission. There are couple of ways to do that, Custom Action tag has a Attribute called **Rights** that can take up any of the 33 inbuilt permissions SharePoint has.Refer to [this article](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/andrevala/archive/2008/08/11/SharePoint-2007-Deployment_3A00_-Custom-Action-Features.aspx) for more details. Else you can create a custom class that will decide when you want to show the menu item based on the custom logic Refer to [this](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/10/15/security-trimmed-custom-actions.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks, but is It possible to show/hide CustomAction dependend of metadata on a ListItem?